# How To Convert Text Into Numbers

Tags: wordpress, text, contenteditable

i want to copy text from my Wordpress site and when i use it some text don't fully copied like when it contain " or , so i want to convert text into special codes like this is text in hindi

सुनो!! दिल ❤ धड़कने लगता है ख़यालों से ही, 
ना जाने क्या हाल होगा मुलाक़ातों में.

and in special code it is like

&#2360 &#2369 न&#2379 !! &#2342 &#2367 &#2354 &#10084 &#2343 ड

ना जाने क्या हाल होगा मुलाक़ातों में

how can i get this in Wordpress content ?

i have searched a lot in google but found nothing

currently i am using this in my Wordpress content

```
<?php
$content = get_the_content();
$newcontent = preg_replace('#<br\s*/?>#i', "\n", $content);
$result = preg_replace('#</p\s*/?>#i', "\n", $newcontent);
echo $result;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert spectial characters into hex with this function from [PHP: bin2hex - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php)

```
function hexentities($str) {
    $return = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
        $return .= '&#x'.bin2hex(substr($str, $i, 1)).';';
    }
    return $return;
}
$content = "सुनो!! दिल ❤ धड़कने लगता है ख़यालों से";

echo hexentities($content);
```

Will render

```
&#xe0;&#xa4;&#xb8;&#xe0;&#xa5;&#x81;&#xe0;&#xa4;&#xa8;&#xe0;&#xa5;&#x8b;&#x21;&#x21;&#x20;&#xe0;&#xa4;&#xa6;&#xe0;&#xa4;&#xbf;&#xe0;&#xa4;&#xb2;&#x20;&#xe2;&#x9d;&#xa4;&#x20;&#xe0;&#xa4;&#xa7;&#xe0;&#xa4;&#xa1;&#xe0;&#xa4;&#xbc;&#xe0;&#xa4;&#x95;&#xe0;&#xa4;&#xa8;&#xe0;&#xa5;&#x87;&#x20;&#xe0;&#xa4;&#xb2;&#xe0;&#xa4;&#x97;&#xe0;&#xa4;&#xa4;&#xe0;&#xa4;&#xbe;&#x20;&#xe0;&#xa4;&#xb9;&#xe0;&#xa5;&#x88;&#x20;&#xe0;&#xa4;&#x96;&#xe0;&#xa4;&#xbc;&#xe0;&#xa4;&#xaf;&#xe0;&#xa4;&#xbe;&#xe0;&#xa4;&#xb2;&#xe0;&#xa5;&#x8b;&#xe0;&#xa4;&#x82;&#x20;&#xe0;&#xa4;&#xb8;&#xe0;&#xa5;&#x87;
```